# Using id as variable in querySelectorAll()

Tags: javascript

I need to use an id as variable in `querySelectorAll()` as shown below.

```
var thismodal = "myModal";
var clicked_id,trueModalId;
function openModal(clicked_id) {
    trueModalId = thismodal + clicked_id;
    document.getElementById(trueModalId).style.display = "block";
    // var thisSlides = "mySlides" + clicked_id;
    if($('trueModalId').find('.modal-content').length) {
        alert(trueModalId);
    }

}

function showSlides(){
    var slides = document.querySelectorAll('trueModalId >.modal-content > .mySlides');
}
```

How do I make this work?

Comment: You mean *"how to concat strings?"* ?

Comment: If I need to use concatenation to use variables in `querySelectorAll` then yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like every variable and string concatenation in js works. You forgot the `#` as an indicator for id though

```
var trueModalId = "myModal";
var slides = document.querySelectorAll('#' + trueModalId + ' >.modal-content > .mySlides');
```

Comment: @DenysSéguret a string is a string, why do you think it wouldn't work?

Comment: @DenysSéguret They have the `#` in variable `trueModalId`.

Comment: @DenysSéguret Oh, now I see what you mean by "semantic problem"